# Screen not updating with .update() from turtle library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I'm new with python and i'm trying to create a pong game using the turtle library. The relevant fraction of the code is the following:

```
import turtle

#(and some code for generating the paddle)

#Function
def paddle_a_up():
    y=paddle_a.ycor() #take y cord
    y+=20 
    paddle_a.sety(y) #change y cord of paddle_a
    print(y) #tried to print the y cord

#Keyboard Binding
wind.listen() #listen the keyboard input
wind.onkey(paddle_a_up(), "w")

#Main Game Loop
while True:
    wind.update() #keep update while game run
```

However, the paddle is not moving when I'm pressing 'w', even though I bound this key to the `paddle_a_up` function. I set the `y` coord to `0` and I tried to print the `y` coord inside the bound function, but when I run the program, `y` attains the value of 20 even though I don't press any key. Hope someone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @farhan, and welcome to stack overflow. Please pay a bit more attention to grammar, and try to avoid repeating yourself. This will make it easier for all potential providers of answers, and increase the odds of getting a good solution. I have edited this question a bit for clarity, but in the future, this would be your job.

Comment: thank you so much :). i will pay more attention in the future about grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `turtle` but there is a problem in this line of code:

```
wind.onkey(paddle_a_up(), "w")
```

I'm pretty sure the intent here was to bind this function to a press of the `w` character. However, instead, you called the function, and bound its result to the keypress. This causes two things:

- The value of `y` goes to 20 even before the game starts.
- The `w` key is not really bound to `paddle_a_up`.

Replace the above line with:

```
wind.onkey(paddle_a_up, "w")
```

(no parenthesis after the function's name)

If the rest of your code is correct, then this will solve the problem.